# Can DLL talk to Java webservice?

Tags: java, web-services, dll

Can a DLL plugin inside Internet Explorer at the client side, communicate with Java webservice at the server side?

The DLL is a BHO that captures URL and send it to server in XML format.

Please advice..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, web services and XML nicely work with different programming languages, operating systems etc.

Answer (score 1):

A native (DLL) plugin does not execute inside a security sandbox, and can do anything that the host application (i.e. IE) can do ... including connecting to any accessible remote server.

Of course, for this to happen, the user has to install the plugin.  (And this sort of thing is why users should be very cautious about installing plugins!)